# Make predictions (classification) with nested? data

Tags: classification, nested-data

The goal of this small project is the predict one week in advance whether this athlete is sustaining an injury (binary classification).

The data I have is questionnaire data from 29 athletes, with well-being and training load data. This data is kind of nested, because of the 29 athletes that are in the group. What kind of methods can I use to make predictions? The output of this project should be ONE! model and not a model for every athlete!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The data is a time series if you guys are wondering

Comment: Mixed effects logistic regression.  This method is good because it can a) incorporate nested structure into the estimation, and b) return *probabilities* for the outcome, which is what you should really be looking at as opposed to classification.

Comment: @DemetriPananos, i will dive deeper into this, thanks!

Comment: For a start: you may also just include a dummy for each athlete in your regression model.

Comment: @timm, i was thinking about this too, but then it does not generalize well with new athletes, right?

Comment: I think you are right. The dummy approach is certainly more suitable, if you are interested in the effects and not solely in the prediciton.